# RPM reading using interrupt

Tags: arduino, interrupt

How can I calculate RPM of a motor using interrupt in Arduino where the rpm reading is obtained using the MiniQ robot chassis encoder

Answer (score 1):

last week i found this [example1](http://elimelecsarduinoprojects.blogspot.com/2013/06/measure-rpms-arduino.html) or this [example2](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ReadingRPM) If you have questions you can ask me